# Wrong behavior of mysql with group by and inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables: `orders` and `order_items`. `Orders` has many `order_items`. It may be some `order_items` like this:

```
| id | order_id | product_id |
|  1 |        5 |          7 |
|  2 |        5 |          8 |
```

When I doing query with params only for `order`, and doing `GROUP BY` with having, it's work how I expect, for example:

```
SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders` 
 INNER JOIN order_items AS bonus_items 
 ON (bonus_items.order_id = orders.id) 
 WHERE 
   (DATE(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) >= '2013-12-02' 
   AND DATE(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) <= '2013-12-02' 
   AND orders.status = 'payed') 
   GROUP BY bonus_items.order_id HAVING count(*) = 1
```

This query find orders, that have one order_items(one record with order_id).
But when I add condition for `order_items` `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` not working, and I have orders with different count of order_items, for example:

```
SELECT `orders`.*
  FROM `orders`
INNER JOIN order_items AS bonus_items ON (bonus_items.order_id = orders.id)
 WHERE (DATE(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) >= '2013-12-02'
   AND DATE(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) <= '2013-12-02'
   AND orders.status = 'payed') AND (bonus_items.user_id = 0))
GROUP BY bonus_items.order_id
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

Why I can't use conditions for joined table?

Comment: id appears to serve no purpose. Suggest you dump it.

Comment: can you add the tables and some sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com along with the desired output to the question ?

Comment: No, I have real db, how can this help me?

Comment: @IgorBiryukov if you prepare an example version of your problem it is much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @IgorBiryukov - Using SQL Fiddle helps you by helping us.  If you give us a concrete example to work with it really helps, instead of everything being conceptual.

Comment: ok, thank you, in future I will use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query gives you all orders that have only one item for user 0. Of course such an order can have additional items for other users.

I suppose what you actually want is to limit the results of your first query further such as to get only one-item orders for user 0. You can achieve this by extending your HAVING clause:

```
SELECT orders.* 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN order_items AS bonus_items ON (bonus_items.order_id = orders.id) 
WHERE DATE(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) >= '2013-12-02' 
  AND DATE(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) <= '2013-12-02' 
  AND orders.status = 'payed'
GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING count(*) = 1 and MIN(bonus_items.user_id) = 0;
```

Comment: It some different with what I want. I want take `Orders` that have only one `bonus_item` and with condition for `bonus_item` `bonus_items.user_id = 0`

Comment: I don't understand the difference. My query selects all orders that only have one item. Of these it picks those where the one item has user id 0. How is this different from what you say?